# Find a Select and Add a class to its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm developing a Rails application and I need to dynamically change the list of a Select.
I have to do this by JavaScript adding a class tag to every children.

Problem is, i can't seem to find the correct id of the Select.

The select is made in ruby, and in the browser its information is this.

**The Select in HTML**

```
<select id="relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all" name="relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all" size="8" multiple="multiple">
```

**The Javascript is this**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $('select#relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all').children();

    for (var index = 0;index < list.length; index++){
        if(list[index].html.indexOf("C-") > -1){
            list[index].addClass("atu_si");
        }else{
            list[index].addClass("atu_no");
        }
    }

    $(".relat_atu").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("relat_atu_yes")){
            $(".atu_si").show();
            $(".atu_no").hide();
        }else{
            $(".atu_si").hide();
            $(".atu_no").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for all of your answers. Thanks to you I finally came up with the solution.

I'll post it in case anyone has the same problem.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("select#relat\\[rond_cat_tipus\\]\\[\\]_all").children().each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).html().indexOf("C-") > -1){
            jQuery(this).addClass("atu_no");
        }else{
            jQuery(this).addClass("atu_si");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = $('select#relat\\[rond_cat_tipus\\]\\[\\]_all').children();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wiggin this will work:

```
var list = $('select[name="relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all"]').children();
```

Update:

```
$('select[name="relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all"]').each(function(){
    var list = $(this).children();
    ...
});
```

Comment: I put in an update try to see if that will work for you. The best thing would be if you could explain what will you do with that data. Are you just trying to collect then based on certain events, will the the same form contain the multiple selects or different forms this would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("select[name]").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr("name").indexOf("relat[rond_cat_tipus][]_all")>-1){
                jQuery("*", this).addClass("class-added");
            }
        });
    });
```